# Determine a type safe return value of a function based on an input function being asynchronous or synchronous in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, typeguards

I'm currently working on a project and have encountered an issue I struggle to fix. My goal is to develop a function that takes a function as a parameter. This function will then be wrapped into another function to return it's return value inside a custom class of mine and this function will then be returned. (complicated lol)

```
/**
 * Merge return value of specified function into MyClass instance
 * @param func      Function to merge the return value from.
 */
function merge<P, R>(func: (...args: P) => R) : (...args: P) => MyClass<R> {
    // Return wrapped in function
    return (...args: P) => {
        const value = func(...args);

        return new MyClass(value)
    }
}

const someMerging   = merge((value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)                        // Returns Function: (value: string) => MyClass<number>
const someMerging2  = merge((value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)('test')                // Returns MyClass { data: 1 }
```

Now, I want to advance the function to be able to resolve async functions properly, so that I can use await on the returned function instead of the return value inside my class.

```
type SyncType<T> = T extends Promise<infer A> ? A : T

/**
 * Merge return value of specified function into MyClass instance
 * @param func      Function to merge the return value from.
 */
function merge<P, R>(func: (...args: P) => R) : (...args: P) => R extends Promise<infer A> ? Promise<MyClass<A>> : MyClass<R> {
    // Check if function is asynchronous
    if(isAsync(func)) {

        // Return asynchronous function and await func return value.
        return async(...args: P) : Promise<MyClass<SyncType<R>>> => {
            const value = await func(...args);

            return new MyClass(value);
        }
    }

    // Return synchronous function
    return (...args: P) : MyClasss<R> => {
        const value = func(...args);

        return new MyClass(value);
    }
}

// Before
(async() => {
    // Merge async function
    const someMerging   = merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)                  // Returns Function: (value: string) => MyClass<Promise<number>>
    const someMerging2  = merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)('test')          // Returns MyClass { data: Promise {<pending>} }
})();

// After
(async() => {
    // Merge async function with await
    const someMerging   = await merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)            // Returns Function: (value: string) => Promise<MyClass<number>>
    const someMerging2  = await merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)('test')    // Returns MyClass { data: 1 }

    // Merge synchronous function
    const someMerging3  = merge((value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)                        // Returns Function: (value: string) => MyClass<number>
    const someMerging4  = merge((value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)('test')                // Returns MyClass { data: 1 }

    // Merge async function without await
    const someMerging5  = merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)                  // Returns Function: (value: string) => Promise<MyClass<number>>
    const someMerging6  = merge(async (value) => value === 'test' ? 1 : 0)('test')          // Returns Promise {<pending>}
})();
```

My main issue is to create a proper isAsync function that is type guarded. I have tried some possible solutions, but none of them worked in a way TypeScript liked it.

```
// This apparently doesn't fit the inputted function: T
function isAsync<T extends (...args: P) => R, P extends any[], R extends any>(func: T) : func is (...args: P) => Promise<R> { ... }

// Same as above
function isAsync<P extends any[], R extends any, A = R extends Promise<infer B> ? B : R>(func: (...args: P) => R) : func is (...args: P) => Promise<A> { ... }

// This works for itself but struggles to work inside my function because the type of 'func' is (...args: P) => R & (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
function isAsync(func: (...args: any[]) => any) : func is (...args: any[]) => Promise<any> { ... }
```

I'm glad for any help I might get, thank you :)

Comment: In order to determine whether function is async or nor, you need to call it. It makes things complicated because it can blow up performance. I think it is better to make separate strategy for async and sync functions. By separate strategy I mean separate functions. It is easy to put a restriction for async and sync funcions for such handler. With this approach you dont need `isAsync` anymore

Comment: Does it work for you https://tsplay.dev/mpDRxm ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yes, I have already thought about this solution. In fact I have already developed a version with it as of now. However, somehow I would like to get the version with the single merge function because I somehow know it could work, but struggle to get it to work. My inner perfectionist wants to get this to work haha

Comment: sometimes it worth splitting your logic into smaller chunks.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I've tried a different version than before and feel like I am getting closer, however it still prints an error as you can see here [tsplay.dev/m3zlEN](https://tsplay.dev/m3zlEN)

My main issue is that I don't understand why typescript makes the function after isAsync() an overload instead the actual type of the function. This means I cannot use the type properly to return it, because it will then print the error

Comment: Consitional statement `R extends Promise<A> ?` as a return type will not work in a way you expect. AFAIK, currently it is not well supported

Comment: @captain-yossarian Okay, that's sad to hear. Maybe I'll stick to the separated async and sync function solution then. Thank you though

Comment: If you want to use conditional types as a return type you better stick with function overloadings